# Regarding DocuSign, why can the document originator sign as me?

Tags: authentication

I recently completed a loan process at a bank.  When I went to the bank to close, the banker had the closing documents in DocuSign up on his computer, and he was able to sign AS ME.   How can this type of signature be valid since he could have "signed" as me without me being there at all?

Comment: Most of the electronic "sign" solutions do not provide much (if any) legally binding signatures. It is mostly a workflow thing which works as long as nobody disputes the transaction. If disputed both parties will have to get into a longish and unclear legal fight with ip logfiles and witnesses from docusign to make a potential agreement plausible. If using qualified signatures (in the EU) no agent will be able to sign for you - and you would need to proof how you dispute having given the sig.

Answer (score 1):

They were able to sign on your behalf using DocuSign's **Send On Behalf Of Functionality** (SOBO).

This is not currently part of basic DocuSign accounts but it is a feature they do offer:

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo

Contractually your banker was probably doing this as your **"banking agent"** which is fairly normal for a number of banking activities and transaction types.

It would seem that your **banker may have taken a calculated risk** in doing so if you had not yet authorized him/her to do so. If you had given authorization in some other manner, for example, via e-mail or even verbal confirmation on the phone that may have been enough for the banker to finish the task on your behalf using DocuSign's SOBO functionality. **Most likely your banker was simply following your bank's normal process** and simply acting as the banking agent when signing this for you.

Note: **Your local laws may vary.** It's important to note that every jurisdiction globally will have different laws and/or acceptable banking practices under which the use of digital signing may or may not even be compliant.